# How to check which package depends upon another installed package?

Tags: 16.04, apt

I just did `apt-get upgrade` on my Ubuntu 16 and noticed that `mysql-client` package was updated. I don't remember installing it though.

How to check which package I did install depends upon it?

Comment: Or `apt rdepends --installed mysql-client`.